# echo "\n" does not print newline in csh

Tags: unix, csh

I am wondering why these simple lines are not working in csh :

```
echo "\n" >> outfile   : prints \n in outfile
```

while same command in unix does this.

I even tried `echo -e "\n" >> outfile`

Comment: `csh` is a _command shell_ that is one of several shells that are commonly run on `unix`, which is an operating system. Other shells include `bash`, `zsh`, and `sh` (among others). If you are running the command `echo "\n" >> outfile` in the csh shell, you are (most likely) running on unix (or Linux) already, so saying "same command in unix..." doesn't exactly make sense. Do you have one combination of a shell running on a unix where this works, and another combination where it doesn't?

Comment: Stephen i figured it out. By default my OS is tcsh and in my script i was putting: #!/bin/csh -f . After changing it to tcsh it is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Shell uses by default the built-in function echo, which usually has reduced functionality.
You can use `/usr/bin/echo`.

```
roinf1n# echo "\n"
\n
roinf1n# /usr/bin/echo "\n"


roinf1n#
```